# CSS caching issue

Tags: html, css, caching, header

I am currently in the process of integrating a login/registration system on my website. I integrated my css sheets into the registration system's "header". Everything is working fine except for one small problem.

Everytime I clear my cache and refresh using crtl f5, the page is displays without any css for a few brief seconds before the css is displayed and everything looks good. It looks tacky.

My page in question is this one so you can see what I'm talking about for yourself
http://govpal.ca/register.php

```
<div id="main-wrapper">
                <div id="main" class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="12u">
                            <div class="content">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>GovPal | MyAccount</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="/css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/skel-layers.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/init.js"></script>
        <noscript>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/skel.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style-desktop.css" />
        </noscript>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
    </head>
<body class="homepage">
```

Should I scrap the header file entirely and put the css directly onto teh register page?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: 1. There shouldn't be a div outside of the HTML tag. 2. Your stylesheets shouldn't be in a noscript tag. 3. Noscript tags should not occur outside of the body tag. 4. Your doctype is incomplete. 5. etc, etc, etc 6. [use the W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgovpal.ca%2Fregister.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), the more errors you have the longer it will take for the page to render and the more likely it will render incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your sourcecode! 
You have a div before the opening hmtl tag as well as some other issues.
Also why do you have your css files located in the no script tag?

Remove the html errors and remove the noscript tag around the css files. and everything should work fine...